# C# and ASP - Retaining Variable Value on Button Click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a warning system for another person's website. The premise is simple enough, if the conditions are met and the warningFlag variable is set "", the warning is made and the warningFlag variable is set to "Y".

However it never retains the value and always triggers the warning. I have tried the ViewState and it would not work. Bit confused as to why it would not work as the ViewState should have done the trick. Maybe I am missing something? Can you help out an ASP beginner?

**Page_Load**

```
if (ViewState["warningFlag"] == null)
    ViewState.Add("warningFlag", ""); //Add the flag
else
    ViewState["warningFlag"] = ""; //Reset the flag
```

**Button click event**

```
if (ViewState["warningFlag"].ToString() == "")
{
    if (this.checkForWarning()) //Checks if Warning conditions are met
    {
        ViewState["warningFlag"] = "Y";

        //Warning Message Code goes here
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 2,4 are doing the same thing(not 100% , but with the same final result)

```
if (ViewState["warningFlag"] == null)
    ViewState.Add("warningFlag", ""); //Add the flag
else
    ViewState["warningFlag"] = ""; //Reset the flag
```

If you want to stop getting the Warning do this :

```
if (ViewState["warningFlag"] == null)
    ViewState.Add("warningFlag", "");  
else
    ViewState["warningFlag"] = "x"; //<-------- see this
```

Edit ( after comment)

So change to this :

```
if (ViewState["warningFlag"] == null)
    ViewState.Add("warningFlag", ""); //Add the flag
else

if (ViewState["warningFlag"].ToString() !="Y")
     ViewState["warningFlag"] = ""; //Reset the flag
```

Comment: But what if you want the warning to only no longer appear if the button was clicked?